# Deploying two different Rails app with different Ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, virtualhost

I have two different Rails apps.

One is using Ruby 1.9.3 and another one is using 2.0. I need to host both of these apps on the same Apache2 server.

I tried somthing like this:

```
Listen 81
Listen 82

LoadModule passenger_module /home/admin1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/admin1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-4.0.53
     PassengerRuby /home/admin1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>

  <VirtualHost *:81>
      ServerName test.ap_live_streaming.com
      RailsEnv test
       # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /home/admin1/app/current/ap_live_streaming/public
      <Directory /home/admin1/app/current/ap_live_streaming/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>


  LoadModule passenger_module /home/admin1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/admin1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/passenger-4.0.53
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/admin1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>

  <VirtualHost *:82>
      ServerName test.ap_live_streaming.com
      RailsEnv test
       # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /home/admin1/app/current/do_dashboard/public
      <Directory /home/admin1/app/current/do_dashboard/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

But, while restarting the Apache2 server, it's showing:

```
[Mon Nov 03 14:59:02.547078 2014] [so:warn] [pid 15821] AH01574: module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
```

There are no issues with the virtualhost. But I am little worried about the loadmodules.

Comment: Do you use rvm? It's easy to solve.

Comment: Yup, I am using rvm for maintaining different ruby versions.

Comment: But I am looking for a solution for my httpd.conf with 2 different loadModules.

Comment: I don't think you can load two versions of Passenger, which would make sense given the message you're getting. Pick a single passenger version and let it load/manage the two Rails apps.